# Is the visibility of table aliases out of subselects intentional or a bug?

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the following query:

```
select
  s.word
  ,s.word
  ,x.word
  ,x.s.word

from (select
        s.word 

      from publicdata:samples.shakespeare s

      where corpus = '1kinghenryiv') x

order by
  word
```

It turns out that if one doesn't apply an alias in the subselect, one can reference the expression not just using `word` and `x.word`, but also using `s.word` and even `x.s.word`.

Coming from SQL Server this is surprising for me. It is irritating because it can cause ambiguity errors if there is another table aliased s on the upper level. And it seems wholly superfluous.

Is this behaviour intentional or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aliasing semantics in these cases are indeed a bit wonky, but it would be hard to change them without breaking queries that users depend on, and our primary goal is to ensure that existing queries continue to work.

We do have plans to address some of these issues with our SQL dialect. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 2):

I do think that using dot notation is a feature here vs. bug (which still possible)

If you want to "stop" dot-chain and avoid ambiguity you should provide explicit alias for respective field

For example, below will fail:

```
select
  word
  ,s.word
  ,x.word
  ,x.s.word
from (select
        s.word AS SWORD -- << added alias
      from publicdata:samples.shakespeare s
      where corpus = '1kinghenryiv') x
order by word
```